# How to make video resume properly after microphone search used on Amazon Fire TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I am creating a video player app for Amazon Fire TV using the Google Leanback code (I know it wasn't intended for Fire TV, but I have done what's necessary to make it work - except for this). I have made it so that a video resumes where you left off if you exit the app by pressing the Home button, or if you pause it, watch a different video, and go back.

However, Amazon is rejecting my app because if you do a microphone search while the video is playing and then go back, the video starts over instead of resuming.

What am I missing? Here is my code for startVideoPlayer() and onPause() from the PlayerActivity:

```
private void startVideoPlayer() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    mSelectedMovie = (Movie) getIntent().getSerializableExtra( VideoDetailsFragment.EXTRA_MOVIE );

    if( mSelectedMovie == null || TextUtils.isEmpty( mSelectedMovie.getVideoUrl() ) || bundle == null )
        return;

    mShouldStartPlayback = bundle.getBoolean( VideoDetailsFragment.EXTRA_SHOULD_AUTO_START, true );
    sprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    startPosition = sprefs.getInt(mSelectedMovie.getVideoUrl(), 0);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath( mSelectedMovie.getVideoUrl() );
    if ( mShouldStartPlayback ) {
        mPlaybackState = PlaybackState.PLAYING;
        updatePlayButton( mPlaybackState );
        if ( startPosition > 0 ) {
            mVideoView.seekTo( startPosition );
        }
        mVideoView.start();
        mPlayPause.requestFocus();
        startControllersTimer();
    } else {
        updatePlaybackLocation();
        mPlaybackState = PlaybackState.PAUSED;
        updatePlayButton( mPlaybackState );
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if ( mSeekbarTimer != null ) {
        mSeekbarTimer.cancel();
        mSeekbarTimer = null;
    }
    if ( mControllersTimer != null ) {
        mControllersTimer.cancel();
    }
    mVideoView.pause();
    mPlaybackState = PlaybackState.PAUSED;
    updatePlayButton( mPlaybackState );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sprefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(mSelectedMovie.getVideoUrl(), mVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: when you hit the microphone that will trigger an onPause, so as long as your code there is saving the playhead status and when there's an onResume you're restarting there shouldn't be an issue. Depending on what the user does after a search though you may get a subsequent onStop fired in your app which may be complicating your scenario...

Comment: Isn't onPause called before onStop, though?

Comment: should be. are you doing any logging to track where you are? does your app correctly work if you pause then resume or stop and restart?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly to resume after exiting the app or pausing, watching another video, and then going back to the first video. I've done some stepping through with the debugger, but hadn't thought of putting in logging. I'll give that a try tonight.

Comment: It turns out that it calls onResume, and since I have no code in there, it just sits there. So I added a call to startVideoPlayer, and it now appears to be working correctly. I'll update this with that as the answer if it's accepted by Amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to call startVideoPlayer in onResume, like so:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startVideoPlayer();
}
```